# Обновление страницы после выдачи файла через php

Tags: php, файлы

```js
$params['notice'] = "выдача файла с переадресаницей<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;".HTTP::getURL('passbook')."'>";// заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=load.gif');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize('/upload/load.gif'));
// читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
readfile('/upload/load.gif');
```

Мне нужно чтобы после того как файл пошел на скачку вывелся `$params`

Обычно так вывожу

```js
<?php if ($notice) { ?>
     <div class="alert alert-danger"><?= $notice ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

но в этот раз такое не прокатывает.как можно решить задачку?

Comment: Потому что этот вывод будет воспринят как часть файла (или если браузер умеет правильно размер считать, то даже и не прочитает.)

А куда вы этот params показать хотите? в брузер?

Comment: В текущей постановке -- никак. Вы отдаете файл, а не HTML документ. Совет: реализуйте вывод на странице, где пользователь кликает по ссылке на скачивание файла.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev,проблема в том что файл формируется на лету и после отдачи должен удаляться.Можете посоветовать более удачный вариант реализации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отдать страницу с ссылкой на файл и автоматическим редиректом через `meta`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL-to-file">
```

То есть алгоритм такой:

1. Выводим страницу с ссылкой на файл и авто редиректом через `meta`;
2. Текущий код отдачи файла преносим на новый урл куда будет редирект, в котором отдаем файл и удаляем;
3. На странице с ссылкой на файл выводим сообщение после например 5 сек (которое указанно в `meta`).